# how to specify the version of python in command line for pip install

Tags: python, command-line, pip

While installing OpenBayes module (from .exe file) for py2 i got error: "could not set a key value" (not a python error, but in dialog window)

I tried using pip install from a command line, but still get errors there.

```
Command "python setup.py egg_info" failed with error code 1 in C:\Users\CD3B~1\AppData\Local\Temp\pip-build-m4nnwa4o\OpenBayes\
```

Also not sure which python (2 or 3) is used when i type a command from console(I have both, but it seems that the OpenBayes module doesn't work with  py3.

How should I specify the version while running pip install from command line?

Comment: I have OS Win10

Answer (score 0):

You can do

```
python2.7 /usr/bin/pip install package
```

Comment: Sorry, didn't got it.

Comment: will this help you http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2812520/pip-dealing-with-multiple-python-versions ?

Comment: I finally uninstalled Py3 and I then installed numpy with pip install for Py2, but when I try to install OpenBayes I still get the same error.

I also tried easy_install OpenBayes, but then i get the other Error:
UnicodeDecodeError: 'ascii' codec can't decode byte 0xcc in position 9: ordinal not in range(128)

Answer (score 0):

I once had this error, and for me worked as `pip` 
for `python 2.x` and using `pip3` for `python3.x`